# OnDateSet method is not fired on Android DatePicker

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have the following C# code

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App3
{
    [Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            TextView myText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.myText);
            DatePicker myDatePicker = FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.myDatePicker);
        }                      

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            TextView myText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textWeekDay);
            myText.Text = "Date Changed";
        }

    }    
}
```

I compile the code, launch the application. I see my datepicker, scroll dates there, but nothing happens. (I do not come to the breakpoint in OnDateSet method.) What could be the problem here ?

Comment: How does your `Main.axml` look like? `OnDateSet` is usally used by `DatePickerDialog` and I can't spot one in your code.

Comment: I think you are confusing DatePicker and DatePickerDialog.  The Dialog has an OnDateSet event; the Picker does not.

Comment: If I use DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener and OnDateChanged method, I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the OnDateSet event is part of the DatePickerDialog, which you are not using. Instead you are putting your own DatePicker FrameLayout directly into your layout. But the DatePicker FrameLayout doesn't haven't any events you can subscribe to beyond the generic events that all Views have.

The recommended approach is to use the full DatePickerDialog by subclassing your own fragment and showing it based on a click event.

See this example: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/date_picker/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe useful for someone else.
so suppose you show `DatePickerDialog` on pushing a button like this

```
private void DatePicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Calendar cal = Calendar.Instance;
        int year = cal.Get(CalendarField.Year);
        int month = cal.Get(CalendarField.Month);
        int day = cal.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, year, month, day);
        dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));
        dialog.Show();


}
```

so when you creating `DatePickerDialog` you should pass `this` for second parameter of constructor .
so when you set Date it is calling `OnDateSet()` methode you define in your code